# Why my Shapefile is not loaded into OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, shapefile, javascript, coordinate-system

This is my website for test: http://www.cv.nctu.edu.tw/tonywang/shapefile-js-openlayers/ol_simple.html

I want to put my Shapefile in OpenLayers. I found an example at https://github.com/mattwigway/shapefile-js/tree/openlayers

I tried it and put my Shapefile in OpenLayers using proj4 to convert EPSG:3826 (my Shapefile's projection is EPSG:3826) to EPSG:4326.

But, I can't see my Shapefile on the OpenLayers map. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the picture below, you'll see your Shapefile is actually being displayed on the map. But it's not being projected to your map's reference system.

[image]

Your Shapefile has EPSG:4326 (as you can [see here](http://www.cv.nctu.edu.tw/shapefile-js-openlayers/naturalearthdata/physical/110m-glaciated-areas.prj)) and your map has EPSG:900913. So, in your `ol_simple.js` file, change line:

```
var outProj = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3857');
```

by:

```
var outProj = map.getProjectionObject();
```

And that should do the trick. Your Shapefile should be located where it is expected to.

[image]

Comment: Nice annotation :)

Comment: Sorry, This isn't my shape file. It is from example. My shape file is Grid.shp which is on Taiwan. Can you help me again? Now, I put it on Website.

Comment: OK this way is working on the other shape file. Thanks a lot.